# I can't load any controller but the one with the module name in CodeIgniter HMVC

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, hmvc

So, I'm developing a website in Codeigniter 3 with HMVC, and I've got the following folder structture inside my application folder:

```
core
    MY_Controller.php
modules
    login
        controllers
            Keep_Logged.php
            Login.php
```

So, this is the MY_Controller (I'm using it as parent for all controllers):

```
<?php (defined('BASEPATH')) OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Controller extends MX_Controller   {

    function __construct()  {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->module("template");        
        $this->load->module("login/Keep_Logged");

        $this->Keep_Logged->cookie_authenticate();

        $exceptions = array("login", "login/authenticate");

        if ($this->session->user_id == NULL && !in_array(uri_string(), $exceptions))    {
            redirect("/login", "refresh");
        }
    }

}
```

And this is the Keep_Logged.php

```
<?php 

class Keep_Logged extends MY_Controller 
{
    function __construct()  {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model("login/Login_Model");
        $this->load->helper("cookie");
    }

    function cookie_authenticate()  {
        if ($user = $this->Login_Model->check_login(get_cookie("user_email"), get_cookie("user_password"), TRUE))   {
            $this->session->set_userdata(array(
                "user_id" => $user->user_id,
                "user_email" => $user->email,
                "user_name" => $user->name,
                "user_kind" => $user->kind
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is I can't load the Keep_Logged.php controller, though I can load the Login.php normally (Or any another controller with the same name as it's module). How can I fix this ? I get this errors every time.

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: CI::$Keep_Logged
>
> Filename: MX/Controller.php
>
> Line Number: 59

-

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>
> Type: Error
>
> Message: Call to a member function cookie_authenticate() on null
>
> Filename: D:\xampp\htdocs\CIHMVC\application\core\MY_Controller.php
>
> Line Number: 13

Answer (score 0):

You try to call method of child class in parent class. Move `cookie_authenticate()` method to MY_Controller and call in as `$this->cookie_authenticate()`. Don`t forget to move staff from Keep_Logged constructor to MY_Controller constructor.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem.. The `template` module is also child of `MY_Controller` and is loaded normally.

Comment: Look this question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466391/loading-a-controller-from-another-module-in-codeigniter-hmvc). Maybe problem in Keep_Logged location.